# Android - Background Service running too often

Tags: android, service, alarmmanager, background-service

My code

```
public class BackgroundIntentService extends IntentService {


    public BackgroundIntentService() {
        super("BackgroundIntentService");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        scheduleNextUpdate();
        Log.w("Blabla", "asldad111");
        Log.w("Blabla", "asldad");
        Log.w("Blabla", "asldad");
        Log.w("Blabla", "asldad555");
    }

    private void scheduleNextUpdate() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, this.getClass());
        PendingIntent pendingIntent =
                PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        // The update frequency should often be user configurable.  This is not.


        AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), 5000, pendingIntent);
    }
}
```

To start the service

```
 Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(this, BackgroundIntentService.class);
    startService(serviceIntent);
```

In the MainActivity.

The problem is that I can see in the logcat those logs spamming, not every 5 seconds but twice a second or more.

Where I'm wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The flag you are using `PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT` in

```
PendingIntent pendingIntent =
            PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

should be `PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT`

as quoted on the [developer docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html)

> FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT - Flag indicating that if the described PendingIntent already exists, the current one should be canceled before generating a new one.
>
> FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT - Flag indicating that if the described PendingIntent already exists, then keep it but replace its extra data with what is in this new Intent.

so in your case the current pending intent exists and the new one updates it and fires at the exact moment it is updating the existing pending since you have defined the trigger time to be at **System.currentTimeMillis()**

So what is happening is that the current Pending intent is firing up before the new pending intent updates it ..and once it does that works as per the alarm logic , after the 5000ms interval the pending intent is fired. So there is a race condition here with interleaved alarm triggers and updates via the pending intents.